# React + TypeScript: Defining EventHandler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am adding TypeScript to my React TodoApp and ran into the following error with the event handler: HandlerCreateTodo:

```
ERROR in src/TodoTable.tsx:107:21
TS2322: Type '(event: MouseEventHandler<MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<Element>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>>'.
      Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>, MouseEvent>): void'.
    105 |                     enterTodo={ enterTodo }
    106 |                     handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo }
  > 107 |                     handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
        |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    108 |                     handleClearTodos= { handleClearTodos }
    109 |                 />
```

How can I define this handler correctly?

I have already tried to write the individual points of the error message in the definition of the event handler:

"event: MouseEventHandler<MouseEvent, Event>"

Then the error message disappears in the render area but the following new error message appears:

"Generic type 'MouseEventHandler' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.ts(2707)"

Here is my Code:
(Parents)

```
interface TodoTableProps {
    mockTodos: Array<Todos>
}



let currentTodos: Todos  [];  

export const TodoTable: FunctionComponent<TodoTableProps> = ({ mockTodos }): ReactElement => {
    //Data input
    if(mockTodos){
        currentTodos = mockTodos;
    }
   
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Array<Todos>>(currentTodos);   
    const [enterTodo, setEnterTodo] = useState<string>('');


    //Enter Todo handler
    const handleEnterTodo = (event: any) => {
      setEnterTodo(event.target.value);
    };
  

    //Clear Todo handler
    const handleClearTodos = (event: MouseEventHandler) => {
        const cleanedTodos: Array<Todos> = []
       

        todos.forEach((element: Todos, index: number) => {
            if(todos[index].done == false){

                cleanedTodos.push(todos[index]);
            }
        });
       
        setTodos(cleanedTodos);
        
    }
    

    //Create Todo handler
    const handleCreateTodo = (event: MouseEventHandler<MouseEvent>) => {

        //create new Todo
        const newTodo = {
            //id: todos.length+1,
            id: v4(),
            describtion: enterTodo,
            done: false
        };
     
        setTodos((todos: Array<Todos>) => 
            [
                newTodo,
                ...todos
            ]
        );
        setEnterTodo('');
        
        
    };

    //Delete Todod handler
    const handleDeleteTodo = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        
        const newTodos = [...todos];
        newTodos.splice(todos.indexOf(event), 1);
        
        setTodos(newTodos);   
    }

    //Status handler
    const handleStatus = (event: any) => {
        
        const newStatus = event.done == true ? false : true;
        const newTodos = [ ...todos];
       
        newTodos.forEach((element, index) => {
            if(newTodos[index].id == event.id){
                newTodos[index].done = newStatus;                
            }
        });
        
        setTodos(newTodos);
    }
  
  
    return(
            <>
                <InputBar 
                    enterTodo={ enterTodo } 
                    handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo } 
                    handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
                    handleClearTodos= { handleClearTodos }
                />
                
                <TodosDisplay 
                    todos={ todos } 
                    handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                    handleStatus={ handleStatus }
                /> 
            </>      
    );
}
```

(Child Component)

```
interface InputBarProps {
    enterTodo: string,
    handleEnterTodo: ChangeEvent<HandleEnterTodo>,
    handleCreateTodo: MouseEventHandler,
    handleClearTodos: any
}

export const InputBar: FunctionComponent<InputBarProps> = ({ enterTodo, handleEnterTodo, handleCreateTodo, handleClearTodos}): ReactElement => {
    return(
          <>
            <form>
              <TextField value={ enterTodo } onChange={ handleEnterTodo }/>
              <Button lable= 'ADD'  disabled= { enterTodo == '' } onClick= { handleCreateTodo } />
              <Button lable= 'CLEAR' disabled= { false } onClick= { handleClearTodos } />
            </form>
          </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why dont you set handleClearTodos: MouseEventHandler in child component?

Comment: Is your problem about event Type ?

Comment: I just fixed it. Thank you for your help. The problem was I hade an event argument in my function of the handler.

Answer (score 2):

you can follow as below:

```
import React, {MouseEvent} from 'react';

const Counter: React.FC = () => {
const clickHandler = (
   // When passing a union as a type parameter,
   // you can provide type-safety to a more
   // abstract handlers:
   e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement>
   ): void => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // your code
   }

   return (
     <>
       <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me!</button>
       <a href="/other-page" onClick={clickHandler}>
        Or click me instead!
       </a>
     </>
  );
 }
```

If you need to create your own event with additional fields you can extend it from MouseEvent:

```
 import React, {MouseEvent} from 'react'

 interface CustomEvent extends MouseEvent<HTMLElement> {
    someAdditionalField: number
 }
```